# MySQL count and join to return ordered list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with a join. I've looked at several answers here and just can't seem to apply it to my particular problem.

I have two tables:

A `likes` table with `id`, `user_IP` and `item_id` columns.

An `auctions` table with many columns including `id`, `title`, `subtitle` and `location`. The `id` column in the `auctions` table refers to the `item_id` in the `likes` table.

I am able to get a sorted list of the likes ordered by the item_id count with the following code:

```
    SELECT likes.item_id, count(likes.item_id) 
    FROM likes 
    GROUP by likes.item_id
    ORDER by  count(likes.item_id) DESC
```

What I need is to have the list display all the auctions(title, subtitle and location of each) in order by most liked. I've tried a few things I've found here, such as the code below which gives a syntax error, and I have been unable to produce the output I need.

```
    SELECT likes.item_id, count(likes.item_id), pqc9_auctions.*
    JOIN likes 
    WHERE likes.item_id = pqc9_auctions.id 
    GROUP by likes.item_id
    ORDER by  count(likes.item_id) DESC
```

I think it is most likely very simple but I've been going cross eyed for the last few hours over this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider adding the syntax error message to your question.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom - Well I just queried it by pasting the above code and it didn't give an error it just returns nothing. Not sure why as I didn't change anything that I can tell. I will be sure to post any errors in the future. Machavity's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a simple `JOIN` just be sure to spell out the relationship

```
SELECT likes.item_id, count(likes.item_id), auctions.*
FROM auctions 
    INNER JOIN likes ON likes.item_id = auctions.id
GROUP by likes.item_id
ORDER by  count(likes.item_id) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! I can't vote up your answer as I don't have enough reputation. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Twodogstar You can still accept the answer by clicking the check mark outline under the voting arrows.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Done and thank you. I looked around as I thought there was a way for me to mark it answered but didn't realize the check mark was the way to do so. Thanks for the help.